# Remove any calls in method that originates from a Field Variable in Java JDT Parser

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I want to detect and eliminate all calls from methods in classes which come from Class Types / Field Declaration. I tried to delete the `FieldDeclaration` nodes but without any help. I tried messing around with Bindings but could not figure out anything fruitful.

For Example,

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class TestList implements Closeable {

    ArrayList<String> arrayListOne = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void add2arrayList() {
      String arg01; 
      boolean b1; 
      b1 = arrayListOne.add((arg01 = new String())); 

      return; 
    }
}
```

If this is the code that goes in to JDT Parser, I am NOT expecting to see the "add" call in the output.

Any input on how to solve this problem will be highly appreciated. I come from a very different part of Computer Science, hence my knowledge with `JDT` is very amateur, a detailed explanation will be greatly welcomed.

Comment: If you walk the AST via `ASTVisitor`, `add` (of `arrayListOne.add(...`) will be visit in `visit(SimpleName node)` and `node.resolveBinding()` will be an instance of `IMethodBinding` (which has methods like e. g. `getDeclaringClass()`). But you'd have to show your code so someone can help you at the point where you are stuck.

Comment: Thanks! I can follow the path you are suggesting. Do you think from the getDeclaringClass() method, I can somehow infer if it is originating from a Field Variable? If so, do you have a suggestion? I will try to consolidate some more relevant code in here.

Comment: Do you mean the field `arrayListOne`? I guess in `arrayListOne.add(...` the nodes `arrayListOne` and `add` will have the same parent. Here the instance of the binding of the node `arrayListOne` is `IVariableBinding` which has the method `isField()`.

Comment: I used getParent() but that does not seem to help, sadly. I am unable to go to the declaring Variables from anywhere in MethodInvocation/MethodDeclaration

Answer (score 1):

Store binding references to your member `FieldDeclaration`s before visiting the AST, and use them to compare the `SimpleName` node binding.

Refer below link for the detailed approach:

[How to find whether a member variable is used in a method using code in eclipse jdt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016647/how-to-find-whether-a-member-variable-is-used-in-a-method-using-code-in-eclipse)